# issues with managing scopes of functions and variables in Angular2+ and leaflet.js

Tags: angular, leaflet

I would like to know if and how I could access the global variables in the component inside the Map.on event handler functions

html

```
<div #map id="map"></div>
```

Component

```
private ready = false;

export class HelloComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(private _signalR: SignalR,
    private service: CustomerTrackingService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    const layer = L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
      // attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href='http://openstreetmap.org'>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href='http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/'>CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href='http://mapbox.com'>Mapbox</a>',
      maxZoom: 23,
      id: 'mapbox.streets',
      accessToken: <TOKEN>
    });


    this.map = L.map('map', {
      center: [34.037008, -84.533377],
      zoom: 18,
      layers: [layer, this._floorplan_layer, heatmapLayer]
    });


    let draw = true;
    this.map.on({
      movestart: function () { draw = false; },
      moveend: function () { draw = true; },
      click: function () { this.ready = !this.ready }
      },
      mousemove: function (e) {
        if (this.ready && draw) {
          //DRAW
        }
      }
    });    
  }    
}
```

I use the variables ready and draw to enable and disable drawing. The **draw** is a local variable inside ngOnit() where as the ready is a global variable to the component. However inside the map.on functions the value of **this.ready** is undefined. I keep the **ready** as a global variable because I want to be able to toggle the value externally like using a button click outside the map div.

Comment: did you try with using an arrow function? It is supposed to preserve the value of `this`, as events are executed out of your component. Or else you need to store the component `this` in a var with a closure

Comment: @Kaddath you should turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: @ghybs i would rather find a dupe to flag, but in a hurry right now.. shouldn't actually do this when i have no time :P

Comment: @Kaddath same here, I am sure there should be a dupe, but could not find it with a quick search…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes got the answer thanks to @kaddath. I was able store the component context as a variable locally inside my ngOnInit() and use it as a reference for my global variables.

```
ngOnInit() {
    let context = this;
    let draw = true;
    this.map.on({
      movestart: function () { draw = false; },
      moveend: function () { draw = true; },
      click: function () { context.ready = !this.ready }
      },
      mousemove: function (e) {
        if (context.ready && draw) {
          //DRAW
        }
      }
     });    
}
```